# Sum array of Object Relationship in Laravel Using Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to `Sum` Array `amount` of Laravel Relationship Using `Vuejs` using `computed`.

[image]

By the Way its Return `NaN` Result....

```
   computed: {
        subTotal() {
            return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
                return total + parseFloat(item.deposits.amount);
            }, 0);
        }
    },
```

Thanks.....

Comment: You are using deposits.amount directly which is actually an array hence you cannot use reduce directly on array item but you should do that on item.deposits by iterating through items object.

Comment: Is it correct that your code should loop the `items` variable (which can't be seen in the image? It looks like what you really want is to loop the `deposits`. Because from this code, you're trying to get `item.deposits.amount`, but `deposits` is an array..

Comment: @Jesper yep, as u say, but i dont know how to implement that? Can u give me any hint?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will return an array of sum for all items within the array index wise.

```
computed: {
    subTotal() {
        let itemsum = []
        this.items.forEach(item => {
            if (item.deposits && item.deposits.length > 0) {
                let total_deposit = item.deposits.reduce((total, val) => {
                    return  parseFloat(total.amount) + parseFloat(val.amount);
                }, 0);
                itemsum.push(total_deposit);
            } else {
                itemsum.push(0);
            }                  
        })
        return itemsum
    }
},
```

Comment: As i told it will return you array for sum of all deposits  item wise as items is an array and you want sum of only deposits values. Please mention what output you are expecting properly.

Comment: i want sum of all amount in array `deposits`

Answer (score 0):

1. Do sum relationship in Laravel

   `protected $appends = ['deposit_amount'];`

   `public function getDepositAmountAttribute(){
       return $this->deposits()->sum('amount');
   }`
2. VueJS Computed Property

   `computed: {
       deposit_amount() {
           var amount = 0;
           for(let i = 0; i < this.item.deposits.length; i++) {
               amount += parseFloat(this.item.deposits[i].amount);
           }
           return amount;
       }
   }`